# Is there any other method to uncomment in awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk, gawk

This command works perfect for me to uncomment a line.

```
awk -i inplace '/# MyLINE/ { sub ("^ *#","") } { print }' file
```

Just for curiosity, I am wondering if there are any other methods for "awk" to uncomment a line?

Appreciate all your attention!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all comments:

```
awk -v FS='#' '{$2=""}1' file
```

If you want to remove only whole-line comments:

```
awk -v FS='#' '/^ *#/{$2=""}1' file
```

If you want to uncomment a specific commented line:

```
awk -v FS='#' '/# MyLINE/{OFS="";$1=""}1' file
```

If you want to uncomment all commented lines:

```
awk -v FS='#' '/^#/{OFS="";$1=""}1' file
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I think the OP wants to uncomment a specific line, not remove comments.

Comment: @andreatsh You are probably right, I updated the answer to cover such case.

Comment: I have downvoted this. The only command matching OP's question (the one that is mentioning "MyLine") looks incorrect to me: firstly, the opening single quote is missing; secondly, `OFS=""` removes _every_ `#` in the line (only the first needs to be removed). The latter issue applies to the 4th command too.